# AutoFill first/last name

Tags: swiftui, textfield, autofill

I recently setup associated domains and added password autofill, but I am now wondering how I can autofill their first and last name as seen on some webpages such as below in HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function formSubmit() {
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The form name attribute</h1>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Send form data!">
</form>

<p>Notice that the JavaScript in the head section uses the name of the form to specify which form to submit.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are on iPhone and tap in the textbox above, it shows you your first name in some cases for a quick autofill. Now my questions is, how can I use swiftUI to produce to same concept as above.

Here is my code in SwiftUI so far:

```
@State var displaynamefirst = ""


          TextField("First Name",text:self.$displaynamefirst)
            .autocapitalization(.words)
            .padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:6).stroke(Color("Dominant"),lineWidth:2))
            .padding(.top, 0)
            .submitLabel(.done)
```

Comment: Have you tried `textContentType(_:)`?

Comment: Thank you. Never would of found this. If you want to make an answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `TextField` you can use the `.textContentType(_:)` modifier.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/textcontenttype(_:)-79con)

> One of the content types available in the UITextContentType structure that identify the semantic meaning expected for a text-entry area. These include support for email addresses, location names, URLs, and telephone numbers, to name just a few.

[list of possible contentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype)

---

Example:

```
TextField("First Name",text:self.$displaynamefirst)
        .autocapitalization(.words)
        .padding()
        .textContentType(.givenName)          
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:6).stroke(Color("Dominant"),lineWidth:2))
        .padding(.top, 0)
        .submitLabel(.done)
```